# Solar pump for a fountain 36" water height

Tags: fountain

I am looking for a solar-powered pump capable of driving the water 36" height (and a couple of feet sideways) to retrofit an existing fountain.  I see lots of pumps with solar panels but they can't drive the water that high.  Can I chain 2 panels together and with the right pump get this to work?  And recommendations on a good pump?  I assume 12v/24v with each panel providing 12v.

Comment: that's where you're going wrong, it's not always the power in the pump itself, or the electricity available. In high school I did a research paper on adding power (electricity), and adding magnets (motor strength). You can add either one to make it fore more pressure, you need to possibly add more power to the pump.

Answer (score 0):

There are countless numbers of submersible aquarium pumps on the net ( such as "big al"). They are 110 V AC , so an inverter would be needed. I never looked but the sites may have some low voltage DC pumps.